# Tumblr captions overflow container

Tags: css, themes, tumblr

So, I found a new theme for my tumblr blog, and it had a few issues, which I mostly managed to sort out, but now I'm facing a big one.

The captions, i.e. the comments and images below the content itself, are overflowing over the container that is set.

Here's the code I'm using  http://freetexthost.com/abfqho3n5h

I've done some small changes to it, but nothing major or irreversible, that aren't shown here because this is the original code, so if you see some other major issue, feel free to tell me.

Here's an example of what happens http://two-dames.tumblr.com/post/121988188767/randomguy2015-because-tina-madqueenieb.

Comment: Please, put the piece of relevant code directly in the post. Links may not work after couple of days.

Comment: I don't see code, I just see a link. I don't see what happened I just see a link. Both links are dead. Make sure your question is self-contained and that links are only used for non-essential background info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add word-wrap: break-word to your posts class

```
.posts {
 width: 500px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #aaa;
 font-family: 'Gibson', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 text-align: left;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)    inset;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Edit** 
For your image you could define an img tag with a max-width: 100%; This makes sure the aspect ratio is preserved and scales the image down accordingly.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That helps, thanks, but only for text, not for images in the captions. Do you have any suggestions regarding that? Like for http://two-dames.tumblr.com/post/120108035022/pineappledean-hellsbellscastiel

Comment: I posted an update. I hope this solves your problems :)